# jQuery bannerslider displays blank slide after every valid slide - IE only

Tags: jquery, slider, division, banner

Again Internet Explorer is the one that gives me trouble.
The bannerslider works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but in IE, I get a blank slide after each good slide.  If I take out the link  for each slide, the blank slide disappears, but then the images are not clickable, which is what I want.
It's like IE sees another div that's not there.  I've triple checked the div's, and I don't see any problems there, but I must be missing something.
Help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.bannerslider.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bannerslider.js">    
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("div.bannerslider").bannerslider({
    showNumbers:true,
    showArrows:true,
        subtitleAttr:'title',
    itemAnimation:'fade',
    autoAdvance:5000,
    pauseOnHover:true,
    animationPeriod:1000,
    bottomOpacity:0.5,
    nextButton:'&raquo;',
    prevButton:'&laquo;'
    });
});
</script>

<div class="bannerslider" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="items">
    <div class="item" style="z-index:2;" title="Click for Info" alt=""><a href="info.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="banners/info.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item" style="z-index:2;" title="Click for the Schedule" alt=""><a href="sched.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="banners/sched.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item" style="z-index:2;" title="Read About the Program" alt=""><a href="program.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="banners/program.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```